Prisma Bypasses Try-Catch Blocks, Leading to Server Crashes
I'm using Prisma in my project, and I am encountering an issue where it seems to ignore try-catch statements.
Tried the solution suggested here but couldn't resolve the problem: Using a prisma query with callback seems to ignore try/catch blocks (Node)
Here’s an example of my code:
try {
  await prisma.table.findMany({});
} catch (error) {
  await LogService.crearErrorLog(error);
  throw ClassToSendAnErrorWithPersonalization.internalServer('Some message');
}

I can't control the error, and it seems to bypass the try-catch block entirely. Occasionally, I use the .then() method to handle the result, but that's not the standard approach in my application.
I also tried handling the error using the .catch() method, as shown below:
await prisma.table.findMany({}).catch(async (error) => {
  await LogService.crearErrorLog(error);
  throw ClassToSendAnErrorWithPersonalization.internalServer('Some message');
});

I tested it with both async and non-async methods for error handling, but it still doesn't work.
Does anyone have suggestions or insights on what might be causing this issue?
